# mySQL find similar but not identical records

Tags: mysql

All, I've found out my users have been inputting Customer names all wrong. Below is an example of how they are entering customer names. I guess they thought they needed an account for each residence this guy owns. I have similar entries as well, but the fake middle initial is before the last name. If I wanted to pull a list of customers that share names and emails how would I go about this? I've already used a query I'll include below my example data, but it's missing results like in my example data. Instead it returns other duplicates I want it to return, just not records like 1,2 below.

Example:

```
ID | first Name | last Name | email          | Residence     |
---+------------+-----------+----------------+---------------+
1  | Bill A     | Bob       | bill@bob.com   | 1-2 broad st  |
2  | Bill B     | Bob       | bill@bob.com   | 1-3 broad st  |
3  | Fred       | Jones     | f.jones@me.com | 1 example st  |
4  | Fred       | Jones     | f.jones@me.com | 200 South ave |
5  | Alex       | Man       | Manley@grt.com | 25 N Main st  |
6  | Alex       | Man       | Manley@grt.com | 39 Front st   |
```

Query:

```
SELECT C.ID, R.Customer_ID , C.orgName, C.fName, C.lName, C.email, R.hNumber, R.street, R.aNumber, R.city
FROM Customer C
LEFT JOIN Residence R ON C.ID = R.Customer_ID
JOIN (
    SELECT X.fName, X.lName
    FROM Customer X 
    GROUP BY X.fName, X.lName 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) X ON X.fName = C.fName AND X.lName = C.lName
ORDER BY C.fName, C.lName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use (at least for mysql)

```
SELECT C.ID, R.Customer_ID , C.orgName, C.fName, C.lName, C.email,
       R.hNumber, R.street, R.aNumber, R.city
FROM Customer C
LEFT JOIN Residence R ON C.ID = R.Customer_ID
JOIN Customer C1 on C.ID <> C1.id
LEFT JOIN Residence R1 ON C1.ID = R1.Customer_ID
where 
      C1.fName = C.fName AND C1.lName = C.lName
   or C1.email = C.email
   or <whatever else you like to compare, eg. same adress + same lastname>
group by C.ID
```

or, more general,

```
SELECT C.ID, R.Customer_ID , C.orgName, C.fName, C.lName, C.email,
       R.hNumber, R.street, R.aNumber, R.city
FROM Customer C
LEFT JOIN Residence R ON C.ID = R.Customer_ID
where exists (
   select * from 
   Customer C1 
   LEFT JOIN Residence R1 ON C1.ID = R1.Customer_ID
   where 
      C.ID <> C1.id          
      and (
            C1.fName = C.fName AND C1.lName = C.lName
            or C1.email = C.email
            or <whatever else you like to compare, eg. same adress + same lastname>
          )
 )
```

Of course this will only give you a limited duplicate check, especially if someone is intentionally trying to bypass this (e.g. in a shopsystem, but there are tools and procedures to help you with that).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'll give it a shot in a while and see what I come up with!

Comment: Since I am using mostly sql this is the most accurate for what I wanted! However @Barry answered well with alternative methods that work just as well, if not better.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is no... each way of doing it will probably involve manually identifying a pattern that has been used and modifying it, like using a large case statement... which isn't that "automatic"

Closest would be to use the soundex to tell if they sound the same... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex

If you can use another programming language then I'd recommend something like... http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php but it will be comutationally heavy

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'll check out the PHP similar text function since I've never heard of that